# Remapping keybindings within items loop

Tags: key-bindings, vimscript

This question is really two questions.

First question: Does vimscript support having interpolated strings as values in a dictionary?

Second question: Is it possible to remap keys from within a loop? While items is an obvious choice (to me) for creating the loop, I'm open to other loops if they allow this.

```
" attempted code:
let path_dict = {
  \'o.': './',
  \'o/': "$p_root",
  \'oc': "$p_css",
  \'oh': "$p_html",
  \'oj': "$p_js",
  \'ol': "$p_learn",
  \}

for [keybinding, filepath] in items(path_dict)
  nnoremap <Leader>keybinding :call Notrw(filepath)<CR>
endfor

" desired result:
" nnoremap <Leader>o/ :call Notrw($p_root)<CR>
" nnoremap <Leader>oh :call Notrw($p_html)<CR>
" nnoremap <Leader>oc :call Notrw($p_css)<CR>
" nnoremap <Leader>oj :call Notrw($p_js)<CR>
" nnoremap <Leader>ol :call Notrw($p_learn)<CR>
" nnoremap <Leader>o. :call Notrw('./')<CR>
```

Comment: The question was a joke but [this answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/7132/1841) by Carpetsmoker shows a way to create mappings in a loop. The trick is to use `execute`. (We may have another question with mappings in a loops but I can't find it right now)

Comment: for interpolating variables into commands use the `:exe` command and you can of course create mappings in a loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does vimscript support having interpolated strings as values in a dictionary?

No, but you can have (nearly) arbitrary expressions within dictionary values:

```
let a = {
    \ 'goodbye': variable,
    \ 'world': $ENVVAR,
    \ 'hello': printf('%d', 10),
    \}
```

> Is it possible to remap keys from within a loop? While items is an obvious choice (to me) for creating the loop, I'm open to other loops if they allow this.

Using `execute` it is possible to do anything in a loop.  Any command sequence which can be uttered in a script can be wrapped in a string and `execute`d (possibly up to minor syntax changes).
For instance,

```
for [keybinding, filepath] in items(path_dict)
    execute 'nnoremap <Leader>'.keybinding ':call Notrw('.filepath.')'
endfor
```

Note that execute inserts spaces between successive arguments (such as between `keybinding` and `':call`).  To suppress this you must concatenate the strings using `.`.  An alternative to concatenation is to use `printf`.  Note that since `execute` is effectively what is called `eval` in other languages, standard string validation security warnings apply.

There are two cases where vim allows true "interpolation."

1) In unix/linux (at least), and only in filename arguments, you may use backticks to supply filename(s) as a result of an external command

```
:next `find . -name ver\\*.c -print`
```

Escaping can be difficult.

2) In variable names only, you can use another variable (see `:h curly-braces-names`) interpolated into the name.  For example,

```
my_{adjective}_variable
echo my_{&background}_message
```

refer to the interpolated variable as you'd expect, e.g., `my_blue_variable`, or `my_dark_message`.